# Java Robot clicking is going at 70 clicks per second cannot figure out the math / what is going wrong

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 volatile private boolean mouseDown = false;

private int max = 0;
private int min = 0;
private Robot robot;

public MouseClickListener()
{
    try
    {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent)
{

}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent)
{
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        max = Native.get().getFrame().getCps().getValue() + Native.get().getFrame().getDev().getValue();
        min = Native.get().getFrame().getCps().getValue() - Native.get().getFrame().getDev().getValue();
        mouseDown = true;
        initThread();
    }
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent)
{
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

Hi there, so basically I'm trying to make an auto clicker which clicks at values to a JSlider (a random value between say 9 and 13, just for example).

So on mouse click the initThread method is called, and the clicks per second is worked out ( a random number between the JSlider value, which is from a diff. class), and then from that, I click and then sleep the thread for 1 / randomNum (in seconds) so that it clicks that many times per second.

For some reason it's clicking at like 200cps and lagging my computer out. Does anyone see any problem with my code?

Thanks.

NEW CODE FOR CLICKER;

```
    public class ClickMethod implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("STARTED");
        do
        {
            System.out.println("RUNNING");
            Random r = new Random();
            int random = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            robot.mousePress(BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(BUTTON1_MASK);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / random);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (mouseDown);
    }
}
```

For some reason this only runs once and then isn't called when the mouseDown variable changes.

Comment: You are intending to sleep, but the way youre calculating the sleep time it will work out as zero for any case where random > 1 (integer division: 1/2 = 0).

Comment: @Durandal I've changed it to 1000 / random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is intended to be clicked by you every so often then it creates numerous threads which all click away

```
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent)
{
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        max = Native.get().getFrame().getCps().getValue() + Native.get().getFrame().getDev().getValue();
        min = Native.get().getFrame().getCps().getValue() - Native.get().getFrame().getDev().getValue();
        mouseDown = true;
        initThread();
    }
}
```

You need to remove initThread() from there and call it once somewhere , e.g., in the constructor.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll try this tonight. I assumed that something like that was happening. I will report back on this tonight.

Comment: If you see my new code, it isn't starting when the mousedown variable changes. How can I make it so that it is always checking if (mouseDown)?

Comment: Going to put up a new question, thanks for your help.